# Можно ли в NetBeans размножить кусок текста N-ое количество раз?

Tags: netbeans

Есть ли возможность в NetBeans (8.1) размножать текст, как, например, в `Vim`?

То есть, допустим, я печатаю `-`, затем активирую комбинацию горячих клавиш, затем ввожу `30` и нажимаю `Enter` — результат:

```
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Удерживать Ctrl+d не вариант? =)

Comment: Нет — это не то, это тоже самое, что и `Ctrl+C` → удерживать `Ctrl+V` :)  Здесь, по крайней мере для меня, роль играет точность.